# Can @yield() and @section() be used with @include() files?

Tags: laravel

I have 3 views:

> **post/index.blade.php
>
> post/container.blade.php
>
> layouts/app.blade.php**

Index view `@expands('layout.app')` and also `@include('container')`. The Idea behind the container is to use the same structure to show posts in different views. But the thing is that `container.blade.php` is not going to be 100% the same on each view. So I thought maybe I can add an `@yield('append')` on the `container.blade.php` so that way I could add more on that post container, using `@section()`. Like this:

inside the index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

  @include('post.container')

  @section('append')
    <p>This is not being outputted correctly.</p>   
  @endsection

@endsection
```

This `@section('append')` belongs to, or actually matches the `@yield('append')` on the `container.blade.php`. The question is how can this be done? How to add `@section('')` that should belong to `@include()` files in this case `container.blade.php`?

Comment: It would be better to use blade components for this: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#components. You would have a `$slot` inside your container, and do `<x-container> <p>This is being outputted</p> </x-container>`.

Comment: Yes, components are great. But this way I believe It's shorter and cleaner. I may use components inside the container.blade.php but I would like the index.blade.php to have simply an @include and if necessary maybe expand with more items.

Comment: You can pass simple data to an @include like Tirdad's answer below, but it's not simple to inject entire chunks of HTML. For that, blade components are MUCH shorter and cleaner.

Comment: Actually my questions was if yield and section could be used with include files as they can be used with extends files. I know how to do it using components, I'm wishing to do it using the include, or perhaps something very similar that actually includes the container file.

Comment: No they cannot.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to the @Include

```
@php $data=[
        'title' => "test title",
        'description' => ""
    ]  @endphp

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

  @include('post.container', $data)

@endsection
```

Comment: Yes, but in my case this container view will be included inside the index view and show view and some other views, doesn't matter. So the thing is the index and the show view will show the exact same container.blade.php but the show view will also show some more information, for example post comments. Of course I can create another div and place the comments there. But I would like to place them where I @yield  inside the post, if that's possible. And the thing with passing data is that, let's say on the third view which also is a bit different, the comments would be passed unnecessarily.